# Parsing custom binary function in sympy

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, sympy, symbolic-math

I have a string that represents a function, for example

`1 + x - 2^x`

I am aware I can use sympy to parse this expression with `parse_expr`.

Suppose now I have another expression with a binary operator not currently in the grammar, for example

`1 + x my_custom_operator 2^x`

Which should yield

`1 + my_custom_operator(x, 2^x)`

where `my_custom_operator(a, b) = min(a, b)`

Is there a way to parse this in sympy or an alternative means. The true expression is far more complicated, so no regex allowed due to things like nested parenthesis.

Comment: You can use a transformer similar to `convert_xor`: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/4bb9dbfb9eacc69b71155f39ddc036678f3d2381/sympy/parsing/sympy_parser.py#L650

Comment: I have edited my question @OscarBenjamin, not sure if the alters your suggestion